# Migrating to Visual Studio Online from TFS 2010

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

I'm getting the following error during the migration process, I have TFS administrator permissions at both sides of the process.

When checking the changeset in question, I view and get the file, So I don't think it's something wrong with TFS on-premises.

> OH-SCM-009: Error occurred while sync. The item
>   $/Brandbank.WebPlatform/development/Sprints/Dev-Main/packages/AjaxMin.4.48.4489.28432/lib/net20/AjaxMin.dll
>   does not exist on the server, or you do not have permission to access
>   it.

Any ideas on what could be causing this?

Comment: BTW. It's processed over 3000 change sets before this occurs, out of a possible 4012

Comment: Do you know whether you have "destroyed" that file in the past or if there are "deny" permissions on that file/folder that would be preventing you access to it?

Comment: The file hasn't been destroyed and there isn't a deny permission. I can pull the change set locally without issue.

Comment: are you using version  1.0.1.006? Can you please zip up and send us the log files from location <c or d>:\Program Files\OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility\logs and email them to ovsmu@opshub.com

Comment: Hi, I've done as you asked.